# My App Is Crash When Ever I Play Any Video

Tags: java, android

i am working on video player on android and i need help my app open    successfully and show video title but when i click on any video this    is crash..
       [enter image description here][1]

```
package com.apps.videoplayer;



   import android.content.Context; import android.content.Intent; import    android.graphics.Bitmap; import android.media.ThumbnailUtils; import    android.provider.MediaStore; import    android.support.annotation.NonNull; import    android.support.v7.widget.CardView; import    android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView; import    android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.View; import    android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.ImageView; import    android.widget.MediaController; import android.widget.TextView;
   import java.io.File; import java.lang.reflect.Array; import    java.util.ArrayList;
   public class Vadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VdeioHolder> {
   private Context context;    ArrayList<File> VideoArryList;
   public Vadapter(Context context, ArrayList<File> videoArryList) {
   this.context = context;
   VideoArryList = videoArryList;    }
   @Override    public VdeioHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

   View Mview = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_list    , viewGroup , false);


   return new VdeioHolder(Mview);    }
   @Override    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final VdeioHolder vdeioHolder, int i) {    vdeioHolder.txt.setText(MainActivity.fileArrayList.get(i).getName());
   Bitmap bitmapThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(VideoArryList.get(i).getPath() ,    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
   vdeioHolder.img.setImageBitmap(bitmapThumbnail);
   vdeioHolder .CV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(context,PlayVideo.class);
           intent.putExtra("position" , vdeioHolder.getAdapterPosition());
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           context.startActivity(intent);


       }
   });
   }
   @Override    public int getItemCount() {
   if (VideoArryList.size()>0){
       return VideoArryList.size();
   }
   else {
       return 1;
   }    } } class VdeioHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{    TextView txt;    ImageView img;    CardView CV;    VdeioHolder (View view){
   super(view);
   txt = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_thum);
   img  = view.findViewById(R.id.im_thum);
   CV = view.findViewById(R.id.myCard);    } }
```

logcat
       it should work okay but its crash

1. List item

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vipGn.png   [2]:    https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO9Wl.png

Comment: Post the stack trace from logcat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)